# Reset predictable Network Interface Names

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a RPi 4 8GB with the latest Raspberry Pi OS. I have two Wifi-Interfaces:

- Onboard wifi (first `wlan0` -> now `wlan1`)
- usb wifi (predictable name `wlx00c0cXXXXX`)

The Onboard wifi named `wlan0` till i connect the usb-wifi-stick and boot several times. now the onboard-wifi named `wlan1`. in `raspi-config` i enable the predictable name scheme.

Is it possible to reset the names of the onboard network interface or change it back to `wlan0`? Why this happend? who to prevent this behaviour next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily rename your network interfaces with:

```
ip link set wlan1 down
ip link set wlan1 name wlan0
ip link set wlan0 up
```

that is, assuming that you don't have any lingering `wlan0` on your Pi.

In the boot messages, you can find some more information. On virtual machines with "predictable" network names, I use the following code in the provisioning script:

```
ETH1=$(dmesg | grep -i 'renamed from eth1' | sed -n 's/: renamed from eth1//;s/.* //p')
ifconfig $ETH1 down
ip link set $ETH1 name eth1
```

You may do something comparable on the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

> i enable the predictable name scheme

so I assume that you want to use that. If it doesn't work as expected, you can try to append this to the line in `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

```
net.ifnames=1
```